# JavaScript code conventions - if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, coding-style

Is there any reason why [Crockford recommends](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) using the `else statement` on the same line as the curly bracet?

```
if (condition) {
    statements
} else {
    statements
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just looks nicer than:

```
if(condition){
    statements
}
else {
    statements
}
```

plus it ties in the `if` and the `else` together logically so it's easier to read.

Comment: Exactly, I would say it's a consequence of using the "braces on the same line" style and the fact the alternative just looks wrong because `else` can't appear by itself so it might as well be tied to the `if` it belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of style. He probably wants to save a linebreak to make the code more compact.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason is readability--it's easier to tell that the statements are related. Otherwise it's just a matter of preference (unlike, e.g., positioning of braces after a return statement).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing because of [Section 7.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-142311.html#449) of Sun's Java standards document.  This is the recommended format that Sun suggests, and he kept the same format for his JavaScript recommendations.

Comment: Just FYI, java and javascript are not the same language.

Comment: I did not say (or imply) that they are.  Crawford's document "is inspired by" Sun's documentation, and if you looks at Sun's docs you will see the formatting is exactly the same for If...Else statements.

Comment: Oops, forgot the `<sarcasm></sarcasm>` tags. :) See my answer below.

Comment: :) ha, SO should give that tag to us!

Answer (score 1):

My boss does the same thing, I still don't really know why. It's just formatting..

It's EXACTLY the same as:

```
if(condition){statements}else{statements}
```

There's no different in speed or anything, just preference on your formatting style.

Answer (score 1):

It's a coding convention, just an agreed style.

```
if (condition) {
    // statements
}
else
{
    // other statements
}
```

The above is just as valid a coding convention. Just not the one Crockford decided on.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think the reason is because of "implicit semicolon insertion, always start your curly braces on the same line as whatever they're opening."

[Google's JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)